# Broadcast message to all instances of kubernetes java service

Tags: java, kubernetes

The problem: I have a spring boot service running on K8s. Generally API calls can be served by any pod of my service, but for a particular use case we have a requirement to propagate the call to all instances of the service.

A bit of googling led me to https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/how-to-broadcast-message-to-all-the-pod/10002 where they suggest using

`kubectl get endpoints cache -o yaml`

and proceeding from there. This is fine for a human or a CLI environment, but how do I accomplish the same from within my Java service, aside from executing the above command via `Process` and parsing the output?

Essentially I want a way to do what the above command is doing but in a more java-friendly way.

Comment: K8s provides HTTP APIs for a lot of things, and afaik `kubectl` even uses them under the hood. For example endpoints api is described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/#endpoints-v1-core). I don't know if you have to use APIs, i guess the typical choice would be to use `event`s, e.g. publish to a Kafka topic and have all interested parties subscribe to that topic.

Comment: I have the same idea. Introducing messaging just to ask for a cache refresh doesn't seem economical. Broadcasting a request (and discarding the response) should be a normal thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your spring boot service should be listening to a message queue, and when one service receives a specific HTTP request message to the `/propagateme` endpoint, it sends an event to the topic to all other clients listening to the `Propagation topic`, when the instances receive a message from the topic they perform the specific action

See JMS https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/

Comment: I'd rather not have to setup a whole messaging infrastructure just for this one use though.